# How to monkeypatch requests to save the responses?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, monkeypatching, python-responses

I have a package with a bunch of classes that act as wrappers for other systems. For example:

```
# mysystem.py
import requests

class MySystem():
   def __init__(self):
      self.session = requests.session()
   
   def login(self, username, password):
      self.session.post("https://mysystem.com/", data={"username": username, "password": password})
```

I also have integration tests:

```
# test_mysystem.py
from mysystem import MySystem

def test_login():
   system = MySystem()
   system.login(username="test", password="P@ssw0rd")
```

I now want to mock out the requests to the real systems so I wouldn't depend on them to run my tests. I will use [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) to register the fake responses into a fixture (I'm using pytest).

The problem is that there are many classes (and more to come), so manually collecting every desired response would be a tedious task. My ideia to automate this, since the integration tests already do the job of requesting every single page I'm interested in mocking up, is to create a fixture that would save all the responses (along with the URL) after a full run of my tests. I could later use the saved information to register my responses more easily.

But how can I monkeypatch the requests made by the sessions that are properties of each system class during testing time?

Comment: `MySystem.__init__` should have the option to receive a pre-made session (or session-like object). Then you don't need to patch anything.

Comment: Or at least a session factory, so that you aren't hard-coding a reference to `requests.session` in `__init__`.

Comment: @chepner there isn't a use case for users to pass a custom session-like object to the systems' constructors, so I don't think this should ever be available to users.

Comment: You already found such a use-case: testing. But just because *you* haven't thought of a reason to use a different session type doesn't mean your users won't, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to do a record/replay of the network calls and responses.

I know a couple of libraries you can use:

- [pytest-automock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-automock/)
- [vcrpy](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) - which has a couple of pytest/unittest wrappers: [pytest-recording](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-recording/), [vcrpy-unittest](https://pypi.org/project/vcrpy-unittest/), [pytest-vcr](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-vcr/)

The basic principle is the same: each library has a "record mode", where you run your code once and the actual network calls are made and serialized into some file. When the tests are run afterward - the file is deserialized and used to replay the same response instead of making the network call.

With `pytest-recording`, all you need is to add the `vcr` mark to the test you want to be recorded:

```
# test_mysystem.py
import pytest
from mysystem import MySystem

# Alternatively, you can add the mark to pytestmark to mark all the methods in the module
# pytestmark = pytest.mark.vcr(filter_post_data_parameters=["password"])

@pytest.mark.vcr(filter_post_data_parameters=["password"])
def test_login():
   system = MySystem()
   system.login(username="test", password="P@ssw0rd")
```

Then, the first time you run your test using `pytest test_mysystem.py --record-mode once`, it will proceed as usual but also record all the network interactions in yaml files under the "cassettes" folder.

The next time you run the same command above, the cassettes will be loaded and no actual request will take place. You can make sure this is the case by using the option `--block-network` or even disconnecting your machine from the network.

Be advised that, by default, all the transmitted data will be recorded. In your specific example, you will probably want to leave out the password. Fortunately, `vcrpy` supports [filtering](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#filter-sensitive-data-from-the-request). You can see I already did that in my example by passing `filter_post_data_parameters=["password"]` to the mark.

Comment: `pytest-automock` didn't make the cut because it's used to mock out classes in general and not requests to the network, but `vcrpy` + `pytest-recording` is exactly what I need. I'm editing this answer to include what I ended up doing so I can accept it.